# Magento Checkout is stuck on Billing information step

Tags: magento-1.7

I am new to the magento, and right now, i was working one website.
I did my initial development on my local machine and everything was fine. few days ago I moved the website into test server from my localhost. after that the checkout function is not working properly.

the problem is that i have almost have nothing on that page.
if user is not logged in, then he(she) sees 2 steps as log in, and billing information, but without content. only the titles.

if user is logged in, then he(she) sees step 1 billing information title, and again no content

the website is http://guerrilla.webionaria.com/

user:teste@mail.ru

password:testtest

can anyone help me with this please

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'Fatal error' on your page.
The rendering stops with

```
var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id',
```

The error appears in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml` or in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml` (if you have cart persistence enabled).
In both of the cases, for some reason this code gives an error:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>
```

To find out what the error is you need to enable error reporting and display_errors.
You can do that from index.php.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); 
...
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You can also enable the developer mode by changing this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

to this

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}
```

Then try again. If the error does not appear on your screen look at the source of the page.
If the error does not tell you anything update the question with its contents.

Comment: i tried everything, that you listed here, but no help. no errors, no warnings, nothing. i even replaced the core code of chechout, and themplate files. no help.

Comment: Maybe something overrides that helper. Here is a small script that can let you check the class overrides: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2013/03/get-class-rewrites.html

Comment: thank you guys, the problem disappeared when i moved to new server.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Magento for the first time on my Localhost. And found the same problem. I found the solution in following way:

-- Enabled the error logs in System > Configuration > Developer Tools

-- Then attempted a checkout.

Bam! found the error in var/logs/system.log

The error was due to SOAP. I needed to enable PHP's soap library. And it proceeded well.

Hope it helps someone :)